# ant javac can't find other project compiled classes

Tags: ant, project, javac

The following is a simplified version of my ant script (it's got the project element etc).

I'm new to ant and unable to figure out why 'compileTests' doesn't compile, whereas 'compileFoo' does.

The error I get is 'package does not exist' as the class in the compileTests project can't find the compiled classes in the compileFoo project, even though they've compiled fine, i can see them on the file system and the path to them is listed in the classpath (i assume this is necessary?)

Clearly there is something basic I don't understand. Can someone please help by explaining?

```
<path id="build_classpath">
    <fileset dir="${other_required_jars}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${foo_build_location}" includes="**/*.class" />
</path>


<target name="compileFoo" description="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${foo_source_directory}\test-src" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${foo_build_location}" includes="**/*.java" excludes="" debug="on" optimize="off" deprecation="on" verbose="on">
        <classpath refid="build_classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>


<target name="compileTests" description="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${test_source_directory}\test-src" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${test_build_location}" includes="**/*.java" excludes="" debug="on" optimize="off" deprecation="on" verbose="on">
        <classpath refid="build_classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classpath is wrong. A classpath doesn't contain a set of .class files. It cntains a set of jar or directories, each containing the root of a package tree. So the classpath should simply contain one element : `${foo_build_location}`:

```
<path id="build_classpath">
    <fileset dir="${other_required_jars}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${foo_build_location}"/>
</path>
```

Comment: JB Nizet, thanks for your reply. I've edited this to show that the build_classpath is still required for other jars so I can't delete it as the test project also requires these. Do you know how to edit this so that it uses both the existing jars and the classes from the foo project please?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to ad the directory itself to the classpath, and not all of its .class files.

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thanks for that. This is probably a poor excuse since everyone has to work with the same situation but the ant documentation wasn't very helpful in that all it contained was information on java classes that I wasn't even using. I just assumed there would be something like a list of elements and the applicable elements that are valid within each somewhere. Thanks a lot for your help!